# Configuring Swagger2 with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to integrate swagger2 with my spring boot application but when I try to open swagger-ui page in the browser it gives me following error on the console:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "swagger-ui.html"

Here is my SwaggerConfig Class:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = TestController.class)
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
   private static final String SWAGGER_API_VERSION="1.0";
   private static final String LICENSE_TEXT ="License";
   private static final String title ="Merchant API";
   private static final  String description ="Restful APIs for merchant";

   private ApiInfo apiInfo(){
       return  new ApiInfoBuilder()
               .title(title)
               .description(description)
               .license(LICENSE_TEXT)
               .version(SWAGGER_API_VERSION)
               .build();
   }
   @Bean
   public Docket merchantApi(){
       return  new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .apiInfo(apiInfo())
               .pathMapping("/")
               .select()
               .build();
   }
}
```

Here is my controller class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Api(value="MerchantControllerAPI",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(path="{/id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ApiOperation("Testing")
    @ApiResponses(value={@ApiResponse(code=200, message="Ok",response=String.class )})
    public String getSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id){
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

I following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_jNGn6v4sU). Anybody here who have faced similar problem? Please help me out.

> Blockquote

Comment: I think, that problem will be in your path `@RequestMapping(path="{/id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, it should be `@RequestMapping(path="{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: You use two Mapping (RequestMapping, GetMapping) and also follow the @pivoman's comment

Comment: Not working! Still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove @PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")

also change your TestController as shown below

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Api(value = "MerchantControllerAPI", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ApiOperation("Testing")
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ok", response = String.class)})
    public String getSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide your source code? (bitbucket/github)?

Comment: Why do you use `RequestMapping` and `GetMapping`? They are doing same thing